# Adding and Displaying Books in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Can anyone help me with adding the book to a particular shelf and display the items inside per shelf? My code seems to not put the books in the shelves, and it only displays the Shelf Name, also shows error on println(ph.get(i).displayPH). So far, here's what I have.

Driver Class:

```
ArrayList<Shelves> shl = new ArrayList<Shelves>();
ArrayList<Book> ph = new ArrayList<Book>();

Shelves shl1 = new Shelves("Shelf 1");
shl.add(shl1);
Shelves shl2 = new Shelves("Shelf 2");
shl.add(shl2);

Book ph1 = new Book("BA001", 1990, "McDonalds", "Shakepike", "Novel", shl1);
ph.add(ph1);
Book ph2 = new Book("BA002", 2004, "How to save the world", "Shakepike",  "Non-Fiction", shl2);
ph.add(ph2);
```

Shelves Class:

```
public class Shelves {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Book> ph;

    public Shelves(String name){        
        this.name = name;
        this.ph = new ArrayList<Book>();
    }
    public void displayShelf(){
        for(int i = 0; i < this.ph.size(); i++){
           System.out.println(this.ph.get(i).getTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

Book Class:

```
public class Book {
        private boolean isAvailable;
        private ArrayList<Shelves> shelf;

        public Book(String cNum, int isbn, String title, String author, String classification, Shelves shelf){

            super(cNum, isbn, title, author, classification, shelf);
            this.isAvailable = true;
            this.shelf = new ArrayList<Shelves>();

        }
        public void displayPH(){
               for(int i = 0; i < this.shelf.size(); i++){
                   System.out.println(this.shelf.get(i));
               }
        }
    }
```

Help would be much appreciated!

PS:I already have the Getters and Setters.

Comment: _error on `println(ph.get(i).displayPH)`_ `displayPH` is a function, not a variable. Use `println(ph.get(i).displayPH())` instead.

Comment: Your talking about runtime errors, but the code doesn't compile. `Book` constructor calls `super(...)`, but it doesn't extend a superclass.

Comment: You say you have error on `println(ph.get(i).displayPH)`, but don't show any such call.

Comment: @Andreas, It has the superclass that gets the needed paramter. I didn't add it since it only contains the parameter and constructor.
Also, the error on the print says that "the method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code you are adding multiple books to your Shelves (ArrayList of Book in your Shelves class) which is fine.

But you are also trying to put multiple Shelves  to your one Book (private ArrayList shelf) which is wrong I think.

Following are the code which may solve your problem

Driver Class:

```
Shelves shl1 = new Shelves("Shelf 1");

Book ph1 = new Book("BA001", 1990, "McDonalds", "Shakepike", "Novel");
shl1.addBook(ph1);
Book ph2 = new Book("BA002", 2004, "How to save the world", "Shakepike",  "Non-Fiction");
shl1.addBook(ph2);

shl1.displayShelf(); //Display Shelve name and its book
```

//Another Shelf

```
Shelves shl2 = new Shelves("Shelf 2");

Book book1= new Book("BA003", 1992, "Book Name 1", "Author Name", "Novel");
shl2.addBook(book1);
Book book2= new Book("BA004", 2008, "Book Name 2", "Author Name",  "Non-Fiction");
shl2.addBook(book2);

shl2.displayShelf(); //Display Shelve name and its book
```

Shelves class:

```
public class Shelves {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Book> ph = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Shelves(String name){        
        this.name = name;
        this.ph = new ArrayList<Book>();
    }
    public void displayShelf(){
        System.out.println("Shelve:" +this.name);
        System.out.println("It has following books :");
        for(int i = 0; i < this.ph.size(); i++){
           System.out.println(this.ph.get(i).getTitle());
        }
    }
    public void addBook(Book book){
         ph.add(book);
    }
}
```

Book Class:

```
public class Book {
    private boolean isAvailable;

    public Book(String cNum, int isbn, String title, String author, String classification, Shelves shelf){
       super(cNum, isbn, title, author, classification, shelf);
       this.isAvailable = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: More over you class should not be Shelves. it should be **Shelf**. It is the conversion of Java.